# Showing L1 norm goes to 0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, normed-spaces

I'm stuck on the following problem and would appreciate any hints or solutions. 
 (Hints are preferable at first though)

> Let $\mu$ be a finite measure on $\left(X,B\right)$ and let $\alpha$
>   be a positive function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha(x)/x\to \infty$
>   as $x \to \infty$. Suppose $f_n\to f$ a.e on $X$ and 
>   $||\alpha\circ f_n||_1\leq M<\infty$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$
>
> Show that $\sup_{n}||f_n\chi_{[fn\geq K]}||_1\to 0$ as $K\to \infty$

Source: Old qualifying problem from fall of 1997. http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~mathgp/quals/real/all_medium.pdf

Here are my thoughts: I noticed that $f_n\chi_{[fn\geq K]}$ goes to 0 as $K$ gets large for each fixed $x$. So I was thinking of somehow applying dominated convergence.  The problem, is that you have to do this with $K$, not $n$, which means you have to probably look at some sequence $K_i$?  The other thing is that we need to somehow exploit $||\alpha \circ f_n||_1\leq M$.  I think we can do that by using a simpler function instead of $\alpha$ that is dominated by $\alpha$ for all values greater than a suitable $K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate the pointwise inequality 
$$\left\lvert f_n\right\rvert\chi_{\left[f_n\geqslant K \right]    }   =\frac{\left\lvert f_n\right\rvert}{a\left(f_n\right) }a \left(f_n \right)         \chi_{\left[f_n\geqslant K \right]    }\leqslant\sup_{x\geqslant K}\frac{\left\lvert x\right\rvert}{a\left(x\right)  }a \left(f_n \right) .$$